# How to generate pdf417 barcode in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode, pdf417

I am working on phonegap project. I need to generate pdf417 barcode. I need to encode some data in pdf417 barcode. I googled many sites. But every where its showing pdf417 scanner. can any one suggest me or give me any links.

Comment: This is likely to get closed due to not showing research.  Try the first link (to a github) on a google search of "pdf417 generator javascript"

Comment: @JRichardSnape will it support to mobile platform. I mean I am developing a phonegap app.

Comment: I'm not an expert on phonegap, but the plugin that google finds ([pdf41-js](https://github.com/bkuzmic/pdf417-js)) is pure Javascript, which looks like it could be integrated into phonegap: their description says "PhoneGap/Apache Cordova enables you to write a mobile app using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.".

Comment: @JRichardSnape thanks a lot. worked...:)

Comment: Cool, I'll put it in an answer so it can be voted on/ you can accept in case others find this question when they have similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pure Javascript plugin ([pdf41-js](https://github.com/bkuzmic/pdf417-js) ) that does what you want. It could be
integrated into phonegap: their description says

> PhoneGap/Apache
>   Cordova enables you to
>   write a mobile app
>   using HTML, JavaScript
>   and CSS.

so pure JS can be integrated.

Comment: Now I want to send that generated barcode to email . So I need to convert that barcode to image, can you tell me how to do that

Comment: That's a different question. I'm not an expert, but google " Javascript canvas to image file " and look at first few links - all SO questions.